# Translate a dataframe into a table using R plotly?

Tags: r, dataframe, plotly

I am having a hard time understanding the workings of plotly tables in R. I am not an experienced programmer, thus my question may look naive.

Please consider the following dataframe:

```
data<-data.frame(
SeqName=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
Length=c("440", "511", "1087", "686", "867", "632"),
Cys=c("3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4"),
NT=c("[NA]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]"),
NR=c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]"),
RefSeq=c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
)
```

I can create the equivalent plotly table using the following:

```
plot_ly(
    type = 'table',
    header = list(
        values = list(list('<b>SeqName<b>'),
                      list('<b>Length<b>'),
                      list('<b>Cys<b>'),
                      list('<b>NT<b>'),
                      list('<b>NR<b>'),
                      list('<b>RefSeq<b>'))),
        cells = list(values = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        c("440", "511", "1087", "686", "867", "632"),
        c("3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4"),
        c("[NA]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]"),
        c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]"),
        c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]"))))
```

However, I cannot make a direct jump. For instance, I cannot get the following to work:

```
plot_ly(type = 'table', header = list(values=names(data)), cells=list(list(values=data)))
```

Please, could anyone clarify why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `plot_ly` is expecting an unnamed list only for the values argument of the list given to the cells argument, so you can just pass this to it by using `unname` on your data.frame:

```
plot_ly(type="table",header=list(values=names(data)), cells=list(values=unname(data)))
```

Comment: Wow, that has been raking my brains for 2h! Thanks a bunch, I was just getting there from another thread. And still, this is all just to finally manage to get a tooltip to work on this table, which is another question!..