# Revert data.frame back to vectors in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

Is there a simple, trivial way of reverting a data.frame back to vectors?

Consider the example dataframe below:

```
df<-data.frame(
SeqName=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
Length=c("440", "511", "1087", "686", "867", "632"),
Cys=c("3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4"),
NT=c("[NA]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]"),
NR=c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]"),
RefSeq=c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
)
```

Is there some magical function which would revert it to vectors as in..?

```
magical.function(df)

[1]c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
[2]c("440", "511", "1087", "686", "867", "632")
[3]c("3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4")
[4]c("[NA]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]")
[5]c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
[6]c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
```

Comment: `as.list(df)`, though there's no benefit to that over `df`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank I am actually trying to make another piece of code work, so this is my objective. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543803/translate-a-dataframe-into-a-table-using-r-plotly

Comment: lapply( df, cat) although is only displaying it. If you wanted a comma delimited version, it might be `lapply(df, deparse)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for `dput`. This allows you to get a text representation of R objects.

However, first note that your original character vectors will be converted to factors by `data.frame` so you will need to account for that and convert back if required. Second, the output of `dput` can either be written to a file directly, or written to the console (where you can copy and paste it). You may need to use `invisible` to avoid other returned objects causing confusion.

```
invisible(lapply(df, function(x) dput(as.character(x))))
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
c("440", "511", "1087", "686", "867", "632")
c("3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4")
c("[NA]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]", "[B]")
c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
c("[NA]", "[B][M]", "[B]", "[B][M]", "[B][M]", "[NA]")
```

Of if you want to store the text representations in a character vector, you can use `capture.output` but note that quotations within the vectors will be escaped.

```
capture.output(invisible(lapply(df, function(x) dput(as.character(x)))))
[1] "c(\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\")"                       
[2] "c(\"440\", \"511\", \"1087\", \"686\", \"867\", \"632\")"          
[3] "c(\"3\", \"2\", \"2\", \"2\", \"2\", \"4\")"                       
[4] "c(\"[NA]\", \"[B]\", \"[B]\", \"[B]\", \"[B]\", \"[B]\")"          
[5] "c(\"[NA]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[B]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[NA]\")"
[6] "c(\"[NA]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[B]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[B][M]\", \"[NA]\")"
```

Answer (score 2):

A data.frame is already a list of vectors (of equal length). You can treat it just like a list.

```
class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
is.list(mtcars)
# [1] TRUE
mtcars[["cyl"]]
# [1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
for (x in mtcars) {
  print(length(x))
}
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
# [1] 32
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
a <- apply(df,1,as.vector)
```

Now you can index with

```
a[1,]
```

for the first vector (first column in your dataframe) and so on

Comment: This is one interesting approach! Still it comes off as a matrix to be converted on a second step. Thanks!